# A distinct HTTP status for not logged in vs. not authorized in a RESTful API

Tags: http, rest, http-status-codes, http-status

So send a few different status headers in my API including `404`, `409`, `201`, `302` and the like. Now I'm running into issues with `401 Unauthorized`. I'm currently sending it if a user is not logged in (the entire API is rights managed) or if a user doesn't satisfy the specific access requirements for the particular resource being retrieved/modified.

Now, I also control the frontend client (a jQuery/HTML application), and I'd like to differentiate between the two cases for `401`. Is there a distinct status I should be using for not logged in? Is the best way to handle it to send body content alongside the header?

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Answer (score 34):

You should use [`403`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) to indicate that the user isn't authorized to access the resource. Using `401` is for indicating that the user needs to supply credentials just as you are currently using it. See the descriptions of `401` and `403` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).

Answer (score 7):

As laz say, you should use `403` when you've authenticated the user, but the user doesn't have permission to do what she's asking for.  e.g. you might allow GET'ing a resource, but not DELETE or PUT.

- 401 would be incorrect since it basically says that "I don't recognise these credentials"
- 403 is correct since it says that "You're not allowed to do this"

In any case, the response body should always contain more information, [even when it's an error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315611/proper-way-to-convey-error-messages-during-calls-to-a-rest-service/3380179#3380179).  This allows a client a way out, hopefully moving forward (using embedded links) or by providing enough information on how to proceed (e.g. "My records indicate that you do not have permission to delete XXX, please contact your system administrator and ask for the FOOBAR permission").

Comment: Wouldn't it be "do not have permission to FOOBAR XXX"?

Comment: The "do not have permission to delete XXX" was thought of as a response to a DELETE request, so yes.  If you serve a 403 to a PUT request, you'd word it appropriately.  The FOOBAR thing should have read "FOOBAR role".  The point is to tell the user how they can solve the problem, but that (error message design) is another topic!